# PostgreSQL: Create an index on timestamp::DATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, indexing, casting

I am creating a summary table that sums up all events in a given day.

```
INSERT INTO graph_6(
  day,
  event_type,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM event e 
                  WHERE event_type = e.event_type 
                  AND creation_time::DATE = sq.day)
FROM event_type
CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT generate_series(
                (SELECT '2014-01-01'::DATE),
                (SELECT '2014-01-02'::DATE),
                '1 day') as day) sq;
```

The `creation_time` column is indexed:

```
CREATE INDEX event_creation_time_date_idx ON event USING BTREE(creation_time);
```

However, the query runs a pretty long time even when only querying two days of data with a handful of events (January 1-2 2014).

The `EXPLAIN` on the query is pretty grim - it runs a sequential scan on the `event` table, not utilizing the index at all:

```
->  Seq Scan on event e_1  (cost=0.00..12557.39 rows=531 width=38)
Filter: ... AND ((creation_time)::date = (generate_series(($12)::timestamp with time zone, ($13)::timestamp with time zone, '1 day'::interval))))
```

I assume this is because we compare a casted value - `creation_time::DATE`, not `creation_time`. I have tried indexing the cast:

```
CREATE INDEX event_creation_time_date_idx ON event USING BTREE(creation_time::DATE);
```

But got an error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "::"
```

**Is there a way to utilize PostgreSQL indices on a timezone column casted to DATE?**

Comment: Am I losing JOIN it due to too much SQL JOIN? This is a JOIN duplicate of a  JOIN question *I have asked less than a month ago*. A JOIN vacation and a JOIN good JOIN book JOIN JOIN JOIN!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

An expression in an index declaration should be enclosed in additional brackets, try:

```
CREATE INDEX event_creation_time_date_idx ON event ((creation_time::DATE));
```

Comment: That will only work for timestamp without timezone. Otherwise you will get this error:
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE

Comment: You can get around the timezone issue (sort of) if you pick a timezone and convert to it both in your index and your queries: `creation_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`

Comment: If you are using the solution of @thaddeusmt, just make sure to also use that syntax (cast to utc) in your queries - otherwise it wont use the index. Thanks for the trick. ;)

Comment: Creating an index works fine with thaddeusmt's suggestion. That was half of the solution for me. When querying data, the other half of the solution was found here. https://gist.github.com/cobusc/5875282. Commenting as someone else MAY need the suggestion too.