# Django models DateTimeField index on Date

Tags: django, django-models

Is it possible to index only the date aspect of a models.DateTimeField in Django?

I cant seem to find it in the documentation, and i'm not sure if doing something like this works

```
class Meta:
    indexes = [
        models.Index(fields=['created_at__year', 'created_at__month', 'created_at__day']),
    ]
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34724524/1637351) shows how to do it in Postgres. However, Django's indexes don't support this out of the box. You'll need to manage it yourself via [`migrations.RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/migration-operations/#runsql).

```
migrations.RunSQL(
    "CREATE INDEX foo_created_at_date_idx ON event ((created_at::DATE));",
    "DROP INDEX IF EXISTS foo_created_at_date_idx;",
)
```

Comment: use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50067367/4984493) if you got `ERROR: functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE`

Answer (score 6):

Actually now you can do this:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncDate

#Model
...
class Meta:
    indexes = [models.Index(TruncDate("created_at"), "created_at", name="created_at_date_idx")]
```